# org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss, connection-pooling, mbeans

I am unable to find which jar contains the class org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool. Can someone point me to the right jar file name. I am using Jboss 4.2.2.

Background:
This is related to my earlier question [Spring - Hibernate - JBOSS - No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053681/spring-hibernate-jboss-no-managedconnections-available-within-configured-b)

Although I solved the old problem I still see this error often (when job is ran multiple times). I suspect the beans are holding the db connections for long time. So I am trying to programatically find how many db connections are alive and recycled at different points in my code. I am trying to do this with JBossManagedConnectionPool.

Questions:
1. Please let me know which jar contains JBossManagedConnectionPool and the link where I can download or the location in the JBOSS server folder
2. Is there any other better way to find the connections statistics using hibernate or spring or any other way.

Comment: To find the jar containing the class, try one of the answers in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1342894/3080094) question using all the jars in the JBoss server directory.